# Наложение текстуры на куб

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, three.js

Есть код, но он не работает.

```
let camera, scene, render, container = document.createElement("div");

document.body.appendChild(container);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 600;

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: 
new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/box.png'), side: THREE.DoubleSide})),
cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), material);
scene.add(cube);

render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
render.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
render.render(scene, camera);
container.appendChild(render.domElement);
```

Помогите наложить текстуру на куб, брал обычный цвет, он срабатывал, куб отрисовывался, изображение 200x200 png формат, всё проверенно, лежит в папке которую я указал. В консоли только вот это: THREE.WebGLRenderer 103

Answer (score 2):

Вот этот фрагмент:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: 
new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/box.png'), side: THREE.DoubleSide})),
cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), material);
```

должен бы выглядеть так:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/box.png'), side: THREE.DoubleSide});
cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200) /*или THREE.BoxBufferGeometry()*/, material);
```